# Does DynamoDB allow conditional updates on operators other than "="?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to execute a conditional update if and only if the value of in-memory counter is **greater than** that stored in DynamoDB.

Example - Let's say the value of in-memory counter is 30. The value of the counter stored in DynamoDB is 25. In 1 conditional operation, I want to set DynamoDB value to 30 (because 25 is an old value)

Documentation has the following -

```
Expected allows you to provide an attribute name, and whether or not Amazon DynamoDB should check to see if the attribute value already exists; or if the attribute value exists and has a particular value before changing it.
```

It clearly states that unless you know the old value, u cannot perform the conditional operation.

Is there a workaround using which I can perform the conditional update on 'greater than'?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Amazon-DynamoDB/4503109122817643

What you described is natively supported in the release on Apr 24 2014 called "Improved Conditional Expressions". So you don't need workaround anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with an "atomic operation" as stated in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#API_UpdateItem_RequestSyntax).

If you don't need full atomic nature, you might implement your own 'transnational' approach or use the [one from amazon](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-transactions) (Java)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards DynamoDB transactions. In the future, I wish DynamoDB supports conditional updates on other operators too.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does support other operators for conditional updates.  For the case you're talking about here, you would specify a conditional operator on the attribute field you want to evaluate, and the condition "LT" (less than) the value of your in-memory counter.  In your case, attribute "myCounterName" is less than 30.

In Java (pseudocode):

```
ExpectedAttributeValue expectedValue = new ExpectedAttributeValue()
    .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.LT)
    .withAttributeValue(new AttributeValue().withN("30");

UpdateItemRequest request = new UpdateItemRequest(...);
request.addExpectedEntry("myCounterName", expectedValue);

dbClient.updateItem(request);
```

This code would only update that counter if the current counter in DynamoDB is less than the value you specified.